# is it possible to get an object to travel over 200 mph with magnets

Tags: electromagnetism

> Is it possible by magnetic forces to cause a certain material to travel at speeds over 5000 mph<>?

Comment: and even over 5000 mph I do no how  do you <>?

Comment: Title and body are two distinct questions? Or is one a typographical error?

Comment: welllll<>? Mr H

Comment: Though, with regards to 200 mph, not only is it possible, it's [been done many times over](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maglev#History_of_maglev_speed_records).

Comment: @KyleKanos - 5000 mph has been done as well. Rail gun.

Comment: rail gun and super rail 590 mph I a bullet traini believe it is the answer to much higher speeds

Answer (score 5):

The thing you are asking about is called a [rail gun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railgun) and yes, it has been done; according to the Wiki article, in 2000 the US Navy reached 8600 km/h which is a hair over 5000 mph.

Comment: Or a coilgun/gauss rifle/linear accelerator will work too :)